# React-beautiful-dnd - Attempting to add or remove a Draggable... warning while dragging columns

Tags: react-beautiful-dnd

I have a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-dnd-template-new-ljivw), where I am trying to make react-beautiful-dnd work. It has to have the ability to move the columns horizontally.

However I am receiving the following warning (when trying to drag a column) as you can see in the console:

```
You are attempting to add or remove a Draggable [id: Status]
while a drag is occurring. This is only supported for virtual lists.
```

I am wondering whether it could be related to the fact that the placeholder is not being found by the app?

Abyone can spot what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled across this error myself. In my case, I was using the npm package `uuid` to generate the `draggableId` and `droppableId` directly in-line, such as:

```js
import {v4 as uuid4} from "uuid";
...
<Droppable droppableId={uuid4()}>
...
</Droppable>
```

The problem is that the variable assignment of `uuid4()` to `droppableId` (or `draggableId`) is being assigned *differently* on every render—noting that a new render occurs whenever a `Draggable`/`Droppable` is interacted with—because every render is calling `uuid4()` and returning a *new* uuid, when `react-beautiful-dnd` expects more static values for `draggableId` and `droppableId` that do not change in-flight (i.e., do not change while a drag/drop action is occurring).

Changing these values to a static ID that was linked to the object being moved (such as the database-persisted id or an ID assigned once per page load using `useEffect` with an empty dependency array, such that any and all calls to `uuid4` will only occur once on page load/mount).

Comment: As an additional trouble shooting step, pay close attention to the `console.warn` messages and trace stacks, somewhere the `Draggable`s and/or `Droppable`s are rendering with new `draggableId`s and/or `droppableId`s and are not static. That's how I was able to locate this bug in my code, in my case, simply noticing that the error messages produced in the warning showed all of these new IDs when I thought they were static.